# Django - Getting a list of fields in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, names

I need help in getting a list of fields in a Queryset.

I am using Django shell to test, but I haven't had any luck.

If I do `.values` like below

```
abc = PrescribedMedsSchedule.objects.filter(medication_date=scheduled_date_obj, medication_time__time=scheduled_time_obj) \
        .select_related('prescribed_meds_id') \
        .select_related('prescribed_meds_id__childno') \
        .values(
            'prescribed_meds_id',
            'medication_date', 
            'medication_time', 
            'quantity',
            'form',
            'prescribed_meds_id__name_of_medication', 
            'prescribed_meds_id__childno__child_name',
            'prescribed_meds_id__childno__group',
            'prescribed_meds_id__childno__line_no'
            ).order_by('prescribed_meds_id__name_of_medication')
```

I get the exact column names that I can use in the template, when I type abc in shell.
`QuerySet [{'prescribed_meds_id': 5731, 'medication_date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 4), ....`

But if I use **.only** instead of **.values**,  when I type abc, I get a 
`QuerySet [<PrescribedMedsSchedule: PrescribedMedsSchedule object (6117) ....`

How can I retrieve/display the fields/columns in this queryset?

The reason I am asking is that the fields in the `select_related` tables no longer appears in the HTML template when I use `.only`.

Comment: This code deleted when I posted...  If i use .values, I get <QuerySet [{'prescribed_meds_id': 5731, 'medication_date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 4),...

Comment: If I replace .values to .only, I get #<QuerySet [<PrescribedMedsSchedule: PrescribedMedsSchedule object (6117)>.   I'd like to see the fields in the Queryset

Comment: Edit your question with the content of your comments, it's very difficult to make sense of things if you've included important information in comments.

Comment: markwalker.  I apologize.  I entered the output earlier, but since they were inside '< >', Stackoverflow didn't display it correctly.  Had to figure google real quick how to display items with '< >' here.

Comment: So what do you expect your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use [QuerySet.values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) if you want the resulting queryset to contain dictionaries and [QuerySet.only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only) if you want the resulting queryset to contain model instances.

You can observe that the result query using `values` or `orders` are the same when you print it in terminal.

```
print(abc.query)
```

If you like to still use `QuerySet.only` and retrieve queryset results as an iterable of model instances, then you can access the related fields using the dot operator. For example, to output child name in the template:

```
{% for a in abc %}
  {{ a.prescribed_meds_id.childno.child_name }}
{% endfor %}
```